# Binary search tree height using strings instead of using individual characters

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Okay so ive got this to show the height when only using each character but how do i change this so that instead of me getting the output of 48 when i run this i want it to take the names instead of each individual character so the output should be 5. How would i do that?

```
import java .io.*; 

class Binarysearchtree  
{ 
    // function to return max  
    // of left subtree height 
    // or right subtree height 
    static int findDepthRec(String tree,  
                            int n, int index) 
    { 
        if (index >= n ||  
            tree.charAt(index) == 'l') 
            return 0; 

        // calc height of left subtree  
        // (In preorder left subtree  
        // is processed before right) 
        index++; 
        int left = findDepthRec(tree,  
                                n, index); 

        // calc height of 
        // right subtree 
        index++; 
        int right = findDepthRec(tree, n, index); 

        return Math.max(left, right) + 1; 
    } 

    // Wrapper over findDepthRec() 
    static int findDepth(String tree, 
                         int n) 
    { 
        int index = 0; 
        return (findDepthRec(tree,  
                             n, index)); 
    } 

    // Driver Code 
    static public void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String tree = "Timmothy Mark Malachi Caleb Brendon Micaiah Nathan"; 
        int n = tree.length(); 
        System.out.println(findDepth(tree, n)); 
    } 
}
```